# How to print out an object array that has parameters?

Tags: java

Alright so this is simple enough.

I need to print out all the parameters of an object at a specific index. However, all of the objects are displaying the memory address. I know you have to override the toString method. But I'm not quite sure where.

Any help would be great!

Here is my  Employee class code:

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
private int age;
private String department;

public String getDept(){
    return department;
}//end dept

public void setDept(String dept){
    this.department = dept;
}//end

public String getName(){
    return name;
}//end name

public void setName(String n){
    this.name = n;
}//end

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}//end age

public void setAge(int a){
    this.age = a;
}//end

public Employee (String n,int age,String dept){

    this.name = n;
    this.age = age;
    this.department = dept;

}//end employee
```

}//end class

and here is the code in my main method:

```
public class Company {


public static void main(String [] args){

    Employee[] e = new Employee[13];

    e[0] = new Employee("Counting Guru",55,"Accounting");
    e[1] = new Employee("Counting Pro",45,"Accounting");
    e[2] = new Employee("Counting Savvy",40,"Accounting");
    e[3] = new Employee("Counting Novice",25,"Accounting");
    e[4] = new Employee("Sales Guru",50,"Marketing");
    e[5] = new Employee("Sales Pro",48,"Marketing");
    e[6] = new Employee("Sales Savvy",38,"Marketing");
    e[7] = new Employee("Hiring Guru",58,"Human Resrouces");
    e[8] = new Employee("Hiring Pro",47,"Human Resrouces");
    e[9] = new Employee("Hacking Pro",47,"Information Systems");
    e[10] = new Employee("Hacking Guru",51,"Information Systems");
    e[11] = new Employee("Hacking Savvy",38,"Information Systems");
    e[12] = new Employee("Hacking Novice",23,"Information Systems");


    for(int i = 0;i<e.length;i++){
        System.out.println(e[i]);

    }//end 
}//end main
}//end company
```

Comment: Exactly. But I want to print out all the parameters so I'm not exactly sure how to implement the toString method.

Comment: Return a String that contains all the paramters you want to print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `toString()` in class Employee, perhaps with @Override tag above it.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + ", " + age + ", " + department;
}
```

Comment: I want to print out all 3 parameters though so how do I do that? I understand you have to return the variable you want to show but I have 3 that are different types/

Answer (score 2):

```
class Employee {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[Employee name=%s, age=%d, department=%s]",
            name, age, department);
    }
}
```

Now just loop over the array of employees and just print the employee object as you already have.